# Laodpicture in UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a Tiff that I want to load into a UserForm. I want to be able to get the tiff file based on User input. But first I would like to at least pull a tiff file in the UserForm. Image2 show "Nothing".

```
Image2.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\users\jneely\desktop\NewB Gage Drawings\1LF-35701-BC01T0-20-K1-A.tiff")
```

Comment: `LoadPicture` doesn't support tiff files (or png for that matter). Can you convert to jpg?

Answer (score 0):

i know this can load *.PNG images to userform, might work with tiff too (untested)

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

'corrigé en 64 bits par PL le 11-10-15 , 32 bit version is here  http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp


Private Type GUID
Data1 As Long
data2 As Integer
Data3 As Integer
Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

Private Type PICTDESC
Size As Long
Type As Long
hPic As LongPtr
hPal As LongPtr
End Type

Private Type GdiplusStartupInput
GdiplusVersion As Long
DebugEventCallback As LongPtr
SuppressBackgroundThread As Long
SuppressExternalCodecs As Long
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdiplusStartup Lib "GDIPlus" ( _
token As LongPtr, _
inputbuf As GdiplusStartupInput, _
Optional ByVal outputbuf As LongPtr = 0) As LongPtr


Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipCreateBitmapFromFile Lib "GDIPlus" ( _
ByVal Filename As LongPtr, _
bitmap As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap Lib "GDIPlus" ( _
ByVal bitmap As LongPtr, _
hbmReturn As LongPtr, ByVal background As Long) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipDisposeImage Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal image As LongPtr) As LongPtr


Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdiplusShutdown Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal token As LongPtr) As LongPtr


Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32.dll" (PicDesc As PICTDESC, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As LongPtr, IPic As IPicture) As LongPtr

Public Function LoadImage(ByVal strFName As String) As IPicture 'image en *.PNG
Dim uGdiInput As GdiplusStartupInput
Dim hGdiPlus As LongPtr
Dim hGdiImage As LongPtr
Dim hBitmap As LongPtr

uGdiInput.GdiplusVersion = 1

If GdiplusStartup(hGdiPlus, uGdiInput) = 0 Then
    If GdipCreateBitmapFromFile(StrPtr(strFName), hGdiImage) = 0 Then
        GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap hGdiImage, hBitmap, 0
        Set LoadImage = ConvertToIPicture(hBitmap)
        GdipDisposeImage hGdiImage
    End If
        GdiplusShutdown hGdiPlus
End If
End Function

Public Function ConvertToIPicture(ByVal hPic As LongPtr) As IPicture
Dim uPicInfo As PICTDESC
Dim IID_IDispatch As GUID
Dim IPic As IPicture

Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1

With IID_IDispatch
    .Data1 = &H7BF80980
    .data2 = &HBF32
    .Data3 = &H101A
    .Data4(0) = &H8B
    .Data4(1) = &HBB
    .Data4(2) = &H0
    .Data4(3) = &HAA
    .Data4(4) = &H0
    .Data4(5) = &H30
    .Data4(6) = &HC
    .Data4(7) = &HAB
End With

With uPicInfo
    .Size = Len(uPicInfo)
    .Type = PICTYPE_BITMAP
    .hPic = hPic
    .hPal = 0
End With

OleCreatePictureIndirect uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic

Set ConvertToIPicture = IPic
End Function
```

To be used like this `Image2.Picture = LoadImage("C:\users\jneely\desktop\NewB Gage Drawings\1LF-35701-BC01T0-20-K1-A.tiff")`